# draw random variable from Poisson for every value in matrix

Tags: python, scipy, poisson

I have the matrix b with b.shape = (100,200). For every element in b I want to draw a random variable from a corresponding Poisson distribution with mu = b and store this r.v. in the matrix X.

```
import SciPy as sc
X = sc.stats.poisson.rvs(size = np.empty((100,200)), mu = b)
```

This however raises an exception:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

As far as I've understood ([thanks to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)) this is due to the interpretation of arrays as boolean values. That said, I don't really see the boolean operation, as well as any possible solution (except a nested for loop, which I try to avoid to improve complexity).

Any more beautiful suggestions?

Comment: You want just `size=(100, 200)`. And `scipy` instead of `SciPy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JohanC this is solved.

```
import scipy as sc
X = sc.stats.poisson.rvs(size = (100,200), mu = b)
```